# How long do the Marie Curie IF grant results take to come out?

Tags: funding, postdocs, europe

I submitted a Marie Curie postdoc fellowship at the beginning of September and as of now (Jan) I have not heard back —I have checked the ECAS portal. The website does not give a single Gantt chart or time frame ironically. So I would like to know how long have people waited?

I am also wonder if a long wait is a possible hint of rejection, like with jobs. Has anyone got a feeling that this is case?
I know there is a accepted, reserve, rejected list, which would suggest that this isn't the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Guide for applicants](https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/portal/doc/call/h2020/msca-if-2015-ef/1657607-guide_for_applicants_if_2015_v_2_en.pdf) says that information on the outcome of the evaluation will be available in February 2016. For reference: I applied in the previous round (the timeline was the same give or take a few days) and received a notice that the proposal was approved in the beginning of February. There was no communication before that, so I wouldn't read anything into that.